# Get uncaught error after using nested layout : Uncaught TypeError: jQuery(...).editable is not a function

Tags: jquery, yii2

I'm using Bootstrap 4 with Yii2 x-editable widget by `2amigos` extended from `x-vitalet's x-editable`. I have a nested layout inside my view layout. When I don't use the nested layout, the inline editable works just fine. But when I used the nested layout, it just won't work. I'm not sure but it seems the code somehow was overriden by my nested layout's CSS and Jquery registered in the layout assets and the script won't run; or maybe it has some conflict somehow. I have tried to make the `editable field` inside the `nested layout` instead of the main view layout, but still I got the same error (there are 2 error in console):

```
Uncaught TypeError: jQuery(...).editable is not a function

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'defaults' of undefined
```

This works just fine in my view :

```
 <?php 
use dosamigos\editable\Editable;

$url=Url::to(['home/fetch']);
echo Editable::widget( [
    'model' => $model,
    'name'=>'tema',
    'url' => $url,
    'type' => 'text',
    'mode' => 'pop',    
]);

?>

 <a href="#" id="tema" name="tema" data-type="text" data-pk=<?=$model->id?> data-url=<?=Url::to(['home/fetch']);?> data-title="Enter username"><?=$model->tema?></a>
</h1>
<br/>


<?php

$url = Url::to(['home/fetch']);

$script = <<< JS
$.fn.editable.defaults.mode = 'inline';

$(document).ready(function(){
     $('#tema').editable();
});

JS;
$this->registerJs($script);
?>
```

Actually acording to https://2amigos.us/open-source/editable-widget I simply need to `echo Editable::widget([]);` but it won't work, so I modified it a bit and added the `<a>` anchor tag as in vitalet's documentation here : https://vitalets.github.io/x-editable/docs.html

It works just fine.

The error appeared when I used nested layout :

```
<?php 

$url=Url::to(['home/fetch']);
echo Editable::widget( [
    'model' => $model,
    'name'=>'tema',
    'url' => $url,
    'type' => 'text',
    'mode' => 'pop',    
]);

$this->beginContent('@app/views/layouts/layout2.php');
?>
--other HTML goes here--

<a href="#" id="tema" name="tema" data-type="text" data-pk=<?=$model->id?> data-url=<?=Url::to(['home/fetch']);?> data-title="Enter username"><?=$model->tema?></a>
<?php
$this->endContent();

$url = Url::to(['home/fetch']);
$script = <<< JS
$.fn.editable.defaults.mode = 'inline';

$(document).ready(function(){
     $('#tema').editable();
});

JS;
$this->registerJs($script);
?>
```

I've tried to moved the codes above inside my `nested layout`and pass the `$model` parameter to the nested layout. I even tried to make `use dosamigos\editable\Editable;` after the `beginContent()` and in the nested layout but both to no avail. Please help. Thanks!

Comment: could you please share your DOM?

Comment: @HamedGhasempour Hi, I found out that the required editable asset didn't load in the DOM (missing) when I used nested layout. 

Without nested layout :```</script><script src="/assets/ed7e27b/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="/assets/939d3f87/yii.js"></script>
<script src="/assets/6ca0ef1e/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script src="/assets/1e0e07b/js/bootstrap-editable.js"></script>
<script src="/assets/f17f71a7/js/coreui.min.js"></script>
<script src="/assets/f17f71a7/js/coreui-utilities.min.js"></script>
<script>jQuery(function ($) {
...
```

Comment: @HamedGhasempour So, the `<script src="/assets/1e0e07b/js/bootstrap-editable.js"></script>` is missing when I use nested layout, I didn't know why. I've tried to include `use dosamigos\editable\Editable` in the nested layout page also, but stil failed.

Comment: The x-editable documentation says that `Note to include x-editable after core library (bootstrap, jquery-ui)!` , so I try to include it after the asset for the nested layout is registered. It goes something like this in my nested layout file:
`use app\assets\theEventAsset;
theEventAsset::register($this);
use dosamigos\editable\Editable;
?>`

I wonder if there's something wrong with how I included the file or am I missing something else?

Comment: Create an asset which will include your js into your view. in depends variable of the asset, pass JQuery asset class name.

Like this:
```public $depends = [
        'yii\web\JqueryAsset'
    ];``` Then use this asset in your view. It makes sure your asset will load after jquery asset.

Comment: @HamedGhasempour Thanks! I register the asset but still it gave the same error. I solved it by removing the `$this->endPage()` in my nested layout file, and it works. Only, I don't know why the inline filed displayed wierdly as two separate field for the same inline (it pop out as two field for one inline), might be something to do with the bootstrap 4 CSS. Still trying to figure it out.